# Ploting 3D points from csv file, Python?

Tags: python-3.x, 3d

I a trying to plot values from csv file. there are three columns which i can print them out, however, it doesnt plot the values. 
Any suggestions how to fix the code?
Thanks in advance

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import sys
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import csv

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


with open('text.csv', 'r') as f:
    obj = csv.reader(f)
    X, Y, Z = [], [], []
    for i,row in enumerate(obj):
        if i>0:
             xstring = row[0]
             ystring = row[1]
             zstring= row[2]
##             print (xstring, ystring, zstring)

zdata = float(zstring)
xdata = float(ystring)
ydata = float(xstring)
ax.scatter3D(xdata, ydata, zdata);
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, you want to append the `xdata,ydata,zdata` from each row in the file to the `X, Y, Z` lists and in the end plot (scatter) these lists.
However, your code doesn't append to the lists inside the loop, so you end up applying `scatter` just on the last `xdata, ydata, zdata`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how to fix that?

Comment: Add `X.append(float(ystring))` inside the loop, where the commented print is (and similarly for other coordinate). And in the end do: `ax.scatter3D(X, Y, Z)`

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi, WOuld you please tell me if I have another three columns to add to the same graph, do I do the same steps?